# Adding object data to html form fields

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my simple form html where I want to add the object data to my form fields. I went through Google search and StackOverflow but all of them were talking about jquery implementation, so here is my simple form html where I want to add the object data to my form fields. Since I'm not aware of Jquery, I want to use the Java Script approach.

Below, I have a user form where I want to bind the **details** object to my above form fields, so for that I'm using the below java script approach. I don't know where I'm going wrong. My object data is not getting bound with my form. 
So kindly help me with it.
Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                Name&nbsp<input id="name" type="text" name="name"><br>
                Place&nbsp<input id="place" type="text" name="place"><br>
                Age&nbsp<input id="age" type="text" name="age">  
            </form> 
        </div>
        <script>
            
            var details ={name:'Krishna',place:'India',age:26}; 
            
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=details.name;
            document.getElementById("place").innerHTML=details.palce;
            document.getElementById("age").innerHTML=details.age;
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input>` tags do not have `innerHTML`, use `.value` instead

Comment: palce --> place, for one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @Jaromanda X, there is no **innerHTML** for an input field. Instead, you should try setting the **value** attribute.

```
    <script>
        var details ={name:'Krishna',place:'India',age:26}; 
        document.getElementById("name").value = details.name;
        document.getElementById("place").value = details.place;
        document.getElementById("age").value = details.age;
    </script>
```

This should do the trick.